# Spring Boot Cloud Feign Client error feign.RetryableException: Read timed out executing GET some service*

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

```
  @FeignClient(name = "auth-service", contextId = "authFeignClient", url = "http://localhost:8081")
   public interface AuthFeignClient {
   @GetMapping("/korisnici/korisnickoime/{username}")
   UserDetailsDTO getUsername(@PathVariable String username);
}
```

Gives error

```
feign.RetryableException: Read timed out executing GET http://localhost:8081/korisnici/korisnickoime/admin%40singimail.ac.rs
    at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:277) ~[feign-core-12.3.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:110) ~[feign-core-12.3.jar:na]
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/korisnici")
public class UserController extends BaseController<User, UserDetailsDTO, Long> {
  private final UserService service;

  public UserController(UserService service) {
    super(service);
    this.service = service;
  }

  @GetMapping("/{id}/public")
  public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> getPublic(@PathVariable Set<Long> id) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(service.findByIdPublic(id), HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  @GetMapping("/korisnickoime/{username}")
  public ResponseEntity<UserDetails> getUserByUsername(@PathVariable String username) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(service.findByUsername(username), HttpStatus.OK);
  }



  @GetMapping("/korisnickoime/{username}/id")
  public ResponseEntity<Long> getUserIdByUsername(@PathVariable String username) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(service.findIdByUsername(username), HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  @PatchMapping({"/{id}"})
  public ResponseEntity<UserDetailsDTO> patch(@PathVariable Long id,
      @RequestBody UserDetailsDTO DTO) {
    DTO.setId(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(this.service.update(DTO), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

But with postman I get a result. Get request with gateway route localhost:8080 or direct localhost:8081 request, I don't know what is going on. Latest Spring boot and dependencies with Java 17. Using spring cloud gateway? Maybe that is the problem? Please help!